# JQuery anchor link event handler does not work with "this"

Tags: javascript, jquery

Why this code does not display href link

```
$("a.cliRedir").click(function() {
    alert($("this").attr('href'))
});
```

Comment: Use `this` insetead of `"this"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `this` without double quotes.

```
$("a.cliRedir").click(function() {
    alert($(this).attr('href'))
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Because you are using `"this"` string. Your code now actually searches for an HTML tag named `<this></this>` which is senseless.

`this` is an object and it should be:

```
$("a.cliRedir").click(function() {
    alert($(this).attr('href'))
});
```

Another important point is that you do not need jQuery to get the href, and it is a good idea to use vanilla JS when it is possible, since it improves readbility and performance:

```
$("a.cliRedir").click(function() {
    alert(this.href);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
$('body').on('click','a.cliRedir',function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    alert($(this).attr('href'))
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('a').click(function(){
      alert($(this).attr('href'));
  });
});
```

In you code you are missing semi-colon at alert.